# Toggled divs disappearing when all and one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page in which if the user selects an option, it will show a div.The script works great except when the user selects d (shows a, b, c) and then selects another option like a. This removes a but shows b and c. My issue is that if the user selects c and then a, the script shouldn't remove a as an option.

Below is the script. The ids for the divs are "one box", "two box" and "three box." The fiddle for it is here: https://jsfiddle.net/bcLuo0bg/8/ and a live version is here to play with: http://warranty.2-10.com/TestforYou

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id")=="a"){
        $(".one").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("id")=="b"){
        $(".two").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("id")=="c"){
        $(".three").toggle();
    }
     if($(this).attr("id")=="d"){
        $(".box").toggle();
    } 

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please.

Comment: Please post the HTML.

Comment: Full LP can be viewed her: http://warranty.2-10.com/TestforYou

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to hide all before executing what you want

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    $(".box").hide();
    if($(this).attr("id")=="a"){
        $(".one").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("id")=="b"){
        $(".two").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("id")=="c"){
        $(".three").toggle();
    }
     if($(this).attr("id")=="d"){
        $(".box").toggle();
    } 

});
```

Comment: I would put $(".box").hide(); outside the if portion (but still inside the onclick event)  - that way you only need to include it once as a onclick event and not in each of the conditional if blocks

Answer (score 0):

I would put $(".box").hide(); outside the onclick callback to hide all the divs at first.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.box { display: none; }` to your CSS file. Hiding via CSS is generally far more efficient than using jQuery/javascript because CSS loads first. jQuery/javascript has to wait for the DOM to finished loading.

Comment: I have .box as `display:none` in the CSS. If I remove the code suggested:`$(".box").hide();`, and a user selects a, b,  c and then d, the code removes all boxes. And that is essentially my issue